# Windows NAT homólogo a IPTABLES

Tags: linux, windows

¿Cómo puedo redirigir el tráfico IP entrante proveniente de otros hosts de la red hacia el router mediante el SO y filtrar el tráfico TCP con destino puerto 80 hacia un servidor local HTTP?.

En linux se usa `"echo “1” > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"`para hacer IP fordward, y en windows el homólogo es poner `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\IPEnableRouter"` a 1 para activarlo.

Sin embargo en linux se puede optar por redirigir el tráfico saliente de la máquina (incluido el procedente del fordward) con iptables con: `"iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp –destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT –to-port 8080"` podemos redirigir todo el tráfico IP con destino puerto 80 al 8080 de nuestra misma máquina, ESO quiero hacer con windows.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?, he leído acerca de ***netsh*** pero no se me ocurre algún comando homólogo, ¿Alguna idea?.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Buenas que sistema Windows estas utilizando??? En caso que uses Windows XP debes ir al registro y cambiar uno de los valores que se llama creo que ip_forwarding por ejemplo

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar netsh de la siguiente forma:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 connectport=8080
```

Tal y como se indica en la documentación de Microsoft:

https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc731068(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_1

Comment: Lo sugerido no es equivalente ni de cerca a IPTables.

Comment: Con este comando se redirige el trafico del puerto 80 al puerto 8080, que es lo que finalmente requiere el usuario.

Comment: Si y no. El usuario quiere redirigir el tráfico saliente de su máquina junto al tráfico forward, del puerto 80 al 8080. En primer lugar no estoy tan seguro que lo propuesto funcione igual.

Comment: Pero más importante que esto, todo lo que llegue al puerto 8080, verá como origen la máquina misma, ya que esta está actuando como proxy (en realidad abrirá el puerto 80 y replicará la petición al puerto 8080, vamos un proxy). En cambio, con la regla _IPTables_ que el OP da como ejemplo en Linux, el tráfico que llegue al puerto 8080 seguirá manteniendo el origen. Tu asumes que eso no es importante, pero el OP no lo especifica y yo asumo que busca el mismo comportamiento original.

Comment: Ciertamente, tal y como se indica en la documentación de technet, "se crea una conexión separada a la original". Pero hay que tener en cuenta que la PO da como referencia netsh.